# UWP Notifications are not popping out, but are available in notification tab

Tags: uwp, push-notification

UWP notifications for the default calendar app first pop out, and they will also be on the notification tab. How to achieve this?

By default, our app notifications land on the notification tab without popping out.
For few notifications, we set NotifyPriority as Max. Even they also land on the notification bar without a normal popup

```
        public void Notify(string title, string content, int Id, bool trackTap = false, bool IsDetailed = false, string extraContent = "", NotifyPriority priority = NotifyPriority.Normal, string returnData = "")
    {
        try
        {
            ToastVisual visual = new ToastVisual
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText
                        {
                            Text = title,
                            HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Title
                        },
                        new AdaptiveText
                        {
                            Text = content
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            if (IsDetailed)
            {
                visual.BindingGeneric.Children.Add(new AdaptiveText { Text = extraContent });
            }

            ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent
            {
                Visual = visual
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnData))
            {
                toastContent.Launch = returnData;
            }

            var toast = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml())
            {
                Tag = Id.ToString(),
                Group = "XXXX"
            };

            if (priority == NotifyPriority.Max)
            {
                toast.Priority = ToastNotificationPriority.High;
                toast.ExpiresOnReboot = false;
            }

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerService.Instance.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could mind the code that show the toast in your side?

Comment: I run your code, it could show the popup in the right bottom corner of window. It will hidden into notification tab after swipe right.